# Код устал, и не хочет работать. (В прямом смысле)

Tags: python

Всем привет! Столкнулся с очень глупой проблемой. После правок код не работает. Уверен, проблема очень проста и банальна, но т.к. я новичек я не могу понять что тут не так. До этого переменная 'text' записывалась в файл, сейчас нет. При попытке печати хоть какой-нибудь переменной из функции 'ok', ничего не происходит. Т.е. функция как-будто пустая. Файл и пересоздавал и переименовывал, но все равно пустой. Думаю дело не в нем, т.к. при попытке как-то задействовать функцию print просто не выполняется

Код:

```
from cgitb import text
from encodings import utf_8
from fileinput import filename
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import re


namefile = r'''C:\Users\sajma\Downloads\lesson8 (2)\lesson8\sc.html'''

with open(namefile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
    text = input_file.read() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
meta = soup.findAll('div', class_="iva-item-root-_lk9K photo-slider-slider-S15A_ iva-item-list-rfgcH iva-item-redesign-rop6P iva-item-responsive-_lbhG iva-item-xl-_jicv items-item-My3ih items-listItem-Gd1jN js-catalog-item-enum")

rk = []

def ok():
    for item in meta:
        rk.append({
        'link':item.find('a',class_ = 'link-link-MbQDP link-design-default-_nSbv title-root-zZCwT iva-item-title-py3i_ title-listRedesign-_rejR title-root_maxHeight-X6PsH').get('href')
        })
        print(rk)
        global comp
        global priced
        for comp in rk:
            corre()
            for priced in b:
                priced = priced
                save()


def corre():
    global b
    price = (comp['price'])
    b = re.findall(r'''\d\s\d{3}''', price)


def save():
    text = str(f'https://www.avito.ru{comp["link"]}\n{comp["link"]}\n{comp["link"]}\n\n\n')
    with open('rew.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(text)

ok()
```

[image: Программа никаких ошибок не выдает]

[image: Файл пустой]

Comment: Попробуйте в функции ОК перед и после 
```for item in meta```
Добавить ```Print("1")``` и ```Print("2")``` соответственно, цикл запускается будет выведено 1 и 2, если нет то только 1. 

так же попробуйте после обозначения ```meta = ....``` вывести ее Print(meta), что бы проверить находятся ли в ней данные.

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема действительно оказалась проста и глупа. В переменной 'meta' оказался задан не тот класс.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в функции ОК перед и после

```
for item in meta:
```

Добавить `Print("1")` и `Print("2")` соответственно, цикл запускается будет выведено 1 и 2, если нет то только 1.

так же попробуйте после обозначения

```
meta = ....
```

вывести ее ````Print(meta)```, что бы проверить находятся ли в ней данные.